# Assigning cluster based on minimum distance from a set of lat-long points with assigned clusters

Tags: python, loops, cluster-analysis, distance

I have a dataframe(df1) as below:

```
clust   longitude   latitude
1   77.62279999 12.95248389
1   77.62517676 12.95027966
2   77.62753442 12.93745478
2   77.62753442 12.93745478
3   77.62217671 12.93353553
3   77.62217671 12.93353553
```

I have a another dataframe with set of longitude/latitude(df2). I want to loop over all these points and for each point iterate over all points of df1 and assign the cluster value based on minimum distance.

I can do a for looping and compute distance and but how to assign the cluster with minimum distance. Is looping the best method for such problem or there can be better method like knn or Kd-tree?

Comment: What's the problem? If you compare some point to all 6 cluster-rows and calculate the distance for each, just get the index of the minimum and access column ```clust``` with that index? If metric-trees would help, probably depends on the size of the datasets.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **nearest neighbor *classification***.

For each point of your test set, find the nearest neighbor in your training data and predict is label.

If you have a lot of training days, use an index. K-d-trees probably don't support Haversine distance, so cover trees or R*-trees are probably the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This worked for me:

```
X = np.array(filtered1[['latitude','longitude']])

y = np.array(filtered1['clust'])
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)
neigh.fit(X, y) 
rest_x=np.array(rest1[['Latitude','Longitude']])
rest_y=neigh.predict(rest_x)
```